# filter data using and clause and using greater then operator

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have been using `$filter` in angularjs and its very good. Now i got a requirement where i need to filter and it has to be a and clause. And i need to be able to use greater then symbol also while filtering. I have object like

```
var filterBy = {gender: "Male", location: "50", focus: "true", yearsOfCoaching: ">2"};

$filter('filter')(data, filterBy);
```

Will `>2` work in this case? and is this the right format for using and clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'pick' filter of the angular-filter library (https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#pick) :

```
$filter('pick')(data, function(elem){
    return elem>2;
});
```